# ASP.Net Core 7.0 Angular SPA and integration tests via WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, angular, integration-testing, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm trying to set up an Angular application with ASP.Net Core 7.0 including integration tests. For the integration tests, I utilize a WebApplicationFactory, but somehow every request during the tests returns 404.

So I tried the same setup with a classic ASP.Net Core Web App and this seems to return the correct pages including status code 200.

I'm aware that my pages will be created client side, but I at least expect something to be returned from my server, so what am I missing here?

**Code of the Angular app:**

In my main project

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Name);
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
}
```

In my integration test project

HomeControllerTests.cs:

```
public class HomeControllerTests: IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public HomeControllerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("/")]
    [InlineData("/fetch-data")]
    public async Task Get_EndpointsReturnSuccessAndCorrectContentType(string url)
    {
        // Arrange
        using var client = _factory.CreateClient();
            
        // Act
        using var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Assert.Equal("text/html; charset=utf-8", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Code of the classic Web App**

In my main project

Program.cs:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Name);
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add services to the container.
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

In my integration test project

HomeControllerTests.cs:

```
public class HomeControllerTests: IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;
    
    public HomeControllerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }
    
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("/")]
    [InlineData("/Privacy")]
    public async Task Get_EndpointsReturnSuccessAndCorrectContentType(string url)
    {
        // Arrange
        using var client = _factory.CreateClient();
            
        // Act
        using var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Assert.Equal("text/html; charset=utf-8", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I can probably guess at why you're getting a 404 - the `app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html")` is being hit, but the Angular app doesn't exist within the `wwwroot` directory as it hasn't been built for the tests. Did you get anywhere with this? (I'm just starting to look at how I might do the same thing.)